# Azure blob resource may have been removed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

In my .core web app which uses Kendo file upload, I am trying to upload a 50 MB .mp4 file to Azure Blob storage.

Small files of sizes 5, 10, 20 MB upload just fine.

However big sized file such as 50 MB one, I am getting error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Do I need to add anything in web.config?

I have

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change this setting from `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942074/).
More info here:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to successfully upload a 50 MB file. But when I try to upload a 250 MB file, I am getting "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process." Any thoughts why that could be happening?

Comment: Have you set **Always on** in `application setting` on azure portal? Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/1950).